# How to Add Mails under one thread with Same Subject Line

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, gmail, sendgrid

Can anyone help with this if a mail has Common Subject line it must be added under one thread , much similar the Gmail does . Can this be handled by C# Coding or any other source library  .
 Mail is fired through sendgrid .

Comment: Grouping mails into Conversations cannot be forced by the sender. Its a feature that the reveicing client may provide.

Answer (score 0):

Pretasoc's comment is correct that the mail client determines how messages are displayed and "threaded".

However, if you are sending email via SendGrid and would like to include information so that mail clients know that message replies belong to a thread please see [Send email as reply to thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35521459/send-email-as-reply-to-thread/35530353#35530353)

Comment: I just tried this example and it isn't working. Any chance there has been a change or update to how this is supposed to function? Thank you :)